Strange UDP problems
I am making a simulator box that pretends to be an industrial pump. We make equipment that interfaces with the pump and don't always have a pump available to test the connection. I used and arduino uno with an ethernet shield 2 to do this. The manufacturer of the pump has a very simple communication scheme. A 10 byte packet is sent to the pump via UDP once a second. The IP address and port on the pump are fixed.
I wrote a simple sketch that looks for the 10 byte UDP packet and then does some bitwise examination, then illuminates some LEDs.
Everything seemed to work great at first. I did my initial testing, I would get the packet, the bits would match, LEDs would illuminate. When I went back and tested it again it would not receive anything. parsePacket() always returns zero. The ethernet link is established, the amber LED on the ethernet shield flashes once a second but nothing shows up.
I have two machines that are in known good working order and neither would work with the arduino. They both worked during the initial testing. We do currently have a pump and both machines will operate the pump with no problems.
On a whim I rebooted one of the machines and packets started to show up again on the arduino when connected to that machine. The other machine still shows nothing on the arduino and both machines will operate the pump.
I tried connecting to them with wire shark. I can see both machines sending a 10 byte UDP packet. The source and destination IPs are correct, the port is correct as well. I bet that if I reboot the other machine that it will start working with arduino again.
I'm using the 2.0.2 Ethernet library.
What to trouble shoot next?
It is almost like something drifts slightly out of tolerance over time and the wiznet chip can't handle it or something.
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>

#define PUMP_ON 9
#define LOW_PRESSURE 8
#define CUTTING_HEAD_OPEN 7
#define LINK_ESTABLISHED 6
#define HEAERT_BEAT 5

// MAC address and IP.
byte mac[] = { 0xA8, 0x61, 0x0A, 0xAF, 0x01, 0x92 };
IPAddress ip(172, 16, 0, 106);

// The local port to listen for connections on.
unsigned int localPort = 8682;

// The maximum number of characters to receive from an incoming packet
#define MAX_PACKET_LENGTH 100
// Buffer for holding received packets.
char packetReceived[MAX_PACKET_LENGTH];

// An EthernetUDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
EthernetUDP Udp;

union uint_double_char {
  unsigned int Integer;
  unsigned char Character[2];
};

union BFT_COMMAND_DATA {
  struct {
    bool start : 1;
    bool stop : 1;
    bool reset : 1;
    bool pressure_relief : 1;
    bool adjusting_jet : 1;
    bool enable : 1;
    bool high_low : 1;
    bool valve : 1;
  };
  unsigned char data;
};

union BFT_COMMAND_DATA bft_command_data;

union uint_double_char conversion;

void setup() {
  pinMode(HEAERT_BEAT, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LINK_ESTABLISHED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LINK_ESTABLISHED, HIGH);
  pinMode(PUMP_ON, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(PUMP_ON, HIGH);
  pinMode(LOW_PRESSURE, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LOW_PRESSURE, HIGH);
  pinMode(CUTTING_HEAD_OPEN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CUTTING_HEAD_OPEN, HIGH);
 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
}

void loop() {
  static unsigned long time_second = 0;
  if (millis() - time_second > 1000) {
    time_second = millis();
    static bool light = false;
    light ^= 1;
    digitalWrite(HEAERT_BEAT, light);
  }

  static bool Link_Established = false;
  if ((Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkON) && (Link_Established == false)) {
    // Begin listening on the local port for UDP datagrams
    if (Udp.begin(localPort) == 1) {
      Link_Established = true;
      Serial.println("socket established");
    }
    Serial.println("link established");
  }
  if ((Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) && (Link_Established == true)) {
    Udp.stop();
    Link_Established = false;
  }

  Ethernet.maintain();

  if (Link_Established == true) {
    digitalWrite(LINK_ESTABLISHED, LOW);
    // Look for a received packet.
    int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
    //Serial.println(packetSize);

    if (packetSize > 0) {
      Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
      Serial.print(packetSize);
      Serial.println(" bytes.");

      Serial.print("Remote IP: ");

      IPAddress remote = Udp.remoteIP();
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i < 3) {
          Serial.print(remote[i], DEC);
          Serial.print(".");
        } else {
          Serial.println(remote[i], DEC);
        }
      }
      Serial.print("Remote port: ");
      Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

      // Read the packet.
      int bytesRead = Udp.read(packetReceived, MAX_PACKET_LENGTH);
      Serial.print("Packet contents: ");
      Serial.write(packetReceived, bytesRead);
      Serial.println();
      conversion.Character[0] = packetReceived[4];
      conversion.Character[1] = packetReceived[5];
      Serial.println(conversion.Integer, BIN);

      bft_command_data.data = packetReceived[4];
      Serial.print(bft_command_data.valve);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print(bft_command_data.high_low);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print(bft_command_data.enable);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print(bft_command_data.adjusting_jet);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print(bft_command_data.pressure_relief);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print(bft_command_data.reset);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print(bft_command_data.stop);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.println(bft_command_data.start);

      if (bft_command_data.start == 1) {
        digitalWrite(PUMP_ON, LOW);
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUMP_ON, HIGH);
      }

      if (bft_command_data.high_low == 1) {
        digitalWrite(LOW_PRESSURE, LOW);
      } else {
        digitalWrite(LOW_PRESSURE, HIGH);
      }

      if (bft_command_data.valve == 1) {
        digitalWrite(CUTTING_HEAD_OPEN, LOW);
      } else {
        digitalWrite(CUTTING_HEAD_OPEN, HIGH);
      }
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LINK_ESTABLISHED, HIGH);
  }
}


you could use Processing on your computer to emulate the pump, or at least log the packets as an UDP client ... see if the failure also occurs there ... https://processing.org .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880885/processing-open-udp-socket-for-reading

Are you sure you need to stop() UDP listener if the link is off temporally? try just UDP.begin in setup and no link status based handling

increase the serial baud rate and test again ... reduce the program to simply echo every UDP byte to serial, see if it still crashes

@jsotola It's not really a crash. The Arduino/ethernet shield simply can't seem to receive anything sometimes. The device sending the packets is an omron motion controller. During the "condition" a computer or the pump can still receive those same packets.

@Juraj the stop() doesn't seem to affect anything. I can go back and forth between two ethernet cords (from two different systems) and one is good and the other "appears" dead, but the pump can get data from both.

There is an updated https://github.com/SapientHetero/Ethernet library that claims to work better with the W5500 (which is on your Ethernet Shield 2). Some forum posts on Wiznet forums also talk about instability / not working after some time, but no real conclusion except "did you follow the read UDP payload mechanism outlined in the datasheet?".

@MaximilianGerhardt I tried the suggested library with no change. Two machines that both talk to the pump. One will talk to the Arduino and the other one won't. I can go back and fourth and very consistently one talks and the other doesn't. The amber led flashes once a second for both like it is receiving something, but nothing shows up on one of them.

Network delays or timing jitter might cause the Arduino to miss packets if it’s not handling them correctly.

@liaifat85 Do you have any suggestions on how to handle them. The Wiznet 5500 chip with the ethernet library is the one doing all the lifting. I've both looked at the library and the chips data sheet and I didn't see any way of dealing with jitter or other things for that matter.

The W5500  chip and library don't have built-in mechanisms for handling packet timing jitter or missed packets. Open the Ethernet.h file, and look for the receive buffer size setting: #define ETHERNET_RX_BUFFER_SIZE 512 . You can increase this size to see if it solves the issue.
